# Deleting subdomain A record with wildcard record in place

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, a-record

I have an A record `sub.example.com` and another record `*.example.com`

If I delete `sub.example.com` A record, will there be any resolution issues if they both point to the same IP address?

I am migrating subdomain records to use wildcard and I want to make sure there is no interruption when I delete sub.example.com

Answer (score 1):

If you have both `sub.example.com` and `*.example.com`, per design of the DNS the wildcard kicks into use only for records NOT being `sub.example.com`.

Once you delete `sub.example.com`, the wildcard will then match all records, including `sub.example.com` (after the TTLs have lapsed, but irrelevant if both records in fact have the exact same data anyway).

Comment: There will be no lapse in dns records being responded to correct?

Comment: @ChrisMuench Research what DNS TTL (Time-To-Live) means for DNS resource records. The old value will be cached by DNS servers until the TTL expires.

Comment: But the subdomain will always be availalbe with TTL of 300 on both wildcard and subdomain records?

Comment: @ChrisMuench I don't understand your question. Is there a response to `sub.example.com` because of direct record or wildcard? If yes, then the record will resolve. If no, then it doesn't.